# How can I apply yadif filter to my command using -vf in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://localhost:2117" -vf "movie= logo3.png [logo];[in]
[logo]overlay= 30:70 [out]"  -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -c:v libx264  -maxrate 
1500k -bufsize 1500k -g 40 -r 23 -preset veryfast -threads 1  -f flv 
rtmp://localhost/live/OTA2
```

I'am using this command above for my streaming transcoding , I want apply yadif filter in side -vf " " but i am getting error , so maybe i don't know the syntax 
so someone help me how to apply yadif filter to the current command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use a filter_complex in this case.

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://localhost:2117" 
  -filter_complex "[0]yadif[main];movie=logo3.png[logo];[main][logo]overlay=30:70"
  -c:v libx264 -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 1500k -g 40 -r 23 -preset veryfast -threads 1
  -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 
  -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/OTA2
```

Comment: one time i tried filler_complex , but my input resultion changed to small and quality is down , with out applying any scale